# How would I read the raw text from a txt file from discord chat on a web hosted bot

Tags: javascript, file, discord.js

I currently am using repl.it to host my bot. The goal was to have it read a txt file from discord and upload that to a hastebin using a github my friend showed me. [https://github.com/OGNova/hastebin.js#readme]
I don't think I would have a hard time once I have the contents of the file but I am struggling to figure out how to get the contents. I was going to try this

```
  var attachment = (msg.attachments)
  if (attachment){
    msg.channel.send(attachment.array()[0].url)
  }
```

That gets me the link of the attachment from the message but I can only download it to my computer, I have no clue to get the information to the bot since it's not running off my computer. So I need help getting the contents from the txt file to my bot. Any help is appreciated, thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a get request to the url and convert the data you get into txt. We can use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to do that.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const data = await fetch(attachments[0].url)
const txt = data.text()
```

the `txt` constant here is just a string so now you can do whatever you want with it